# title with button in same line using html css

Tags: html, css

I want create design with image with button in same line but text not come middle of text

html and css code as follow:

```css
  .block-title
  {
    display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      align-content: space-between;
      flex-direction: row;
  }
  .block-title strong{
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="block-title">
  <strong>Shop By Category</strong>
  <button class="c-btn">View Profile</button>
</div>
```

If anyone have idea plz help me in this

Plz check attach image for clarification

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Something like this?

```css
.block-title
{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color:beige;
    padding:10px 20px;
}
.block-title strong{
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.c-btn {
   background-color:#f65f73;
   color:white;
   border-radius:20px;
   border:0px solid;
   height:40px;
   width:180px;
   text-align:left;
   padding-left:15px;
   font-size:20px;
}



button.c-btn:after {
  content:"\01F862";
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color:white;
  height:26px;
  width:26px;
  color:black;
  font-size:19px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-title">
<strong>Shop By Category</strong>
<button class="c-btn">View Profile</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to set `justify-content: space-between;` as opposed to center

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this?

```css
.block-title
{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;

}
.block-title strong{
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.btn-1 {
  background-color: #df3232;
}
.btn-1 .round {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 12px 53px 12px 23px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  display: inline-block;
}
a span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
a .round {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: 3px;
}
a .round i {
  color: #df3232;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -4px;
}

.c_btn {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.45;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="block-title">
    <strong>Shop By Category</strong>
    <div>
      <a href="" class="btn btn-1">
        <span class="c_btn">View profile</span>
        <span class="round"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right "></i></span>
      </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have confsion in how to add image in that button

Comment: Do you want to style the red button?

Comment: Ys with that right arrow icon . I am stuck in that

Comment: Please have a look at my edit. Do you want to make it like this? You can make changes in the css as your desire.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign to the button: `float:right;`

```css
button {
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-title">
<strong>Shop By Category</strong>
<button class="c-btn">View Profile</button>
</div>
```

#### update

```css
button {
  float:right;
}

.c-btn  {
  border: none;
  background-color: magenta;
  padding: 12px 48px 12px 24px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='7.41' height='12' viewBox='0 0 7.41 12'%3E%3Cpath d='M10,6,8.59,7.41,13.17,12,8.59,16.59,10,18l6-6Z' transform='translate(-8.59 -6)' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 24px center;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-title">
  <strong>Shop By Category</strong>
  <button class="c-btn">View Profile</button>
</div>
```

Comment: yes right but i have stuck in button as per the image i have attached. Not getting how to add right arrow in image

Comment: @Praful You already have a class c-btn in your button. you can style your button with this selector. i just added a small example to my answer.